# Permission error running any git command in makefiles

Tags: git, makefile, permissions

I've been slowly going insane from a recurring permission error encountered when running any git command within any makefile:

for instance running make against:

```
a:
    git --version
```

will result in:

```
make: git: Permission denied
make: *** [makefile:<line number>: <target>] Error 127
```

**Observations:**

- occurs for even the most trivial of commands, e.g. git status
- occurs when running as root
- occurs regardless of directory and file permissions
- the given command runs without issue if run directly
- after reformatting and reinstalling my OS the problem went away but has resurfaced after a few months
- BSD bmake seems to work okay

**Environment:**

- Arch Linux x86-64
- GNU Make v4.3
- Git v2.26.2

---

I use makefiles extensively at work and this problem has slowly become more and more frustrating. If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Run:          `which git | xargs ls -l`     and post the output.  It looks like the executable flag is not set.  Running as root will not overcome the lack of an executable flag.  The fact that you can run `git` directly seems to indicate that `make` is seeing a different copy of `git` than you are.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3143720 Apr 20 14:22 /usr/bin/git` -- yea, its not an alias or anything and seems to have the executable bit set

Comment: Can you add the same `which` command to the makefile?  See if it's the same copy of `git`.

Comment: that's a good idea, same location though

Comment: try putting `git --version` in your makefile.  That's more trivial than `git status`.  The status command needs to access the filesystem.

Comment: also add `pwd -P` to your makefile.   Maybe the current directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: `git --version` has the same error, `pwd -P` run in or outside the makefile is the expected working directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be really, really helpful if you provided the recipe you're trying to run that's giving the above error, or even the make output of the command that was invoked.  Without that we can only guess, which is kind of a waste of everyone's time :)

My suspicion is this: you have a directory on your `$PATH` which has a *directory* named `git` in it, and this appears before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`.

There's a bug in GNU make 4.3 (actually the bug was in gnulib, which GNU make uses) which didn't correctly ignore directories when searching `PATH`.

However, this *cannot* be the problem if your recipe invokes `git` in a non-trivial way (as part of a shell script).

The fastest way to check this is just to add a semicolon to your command line; you didn't show us the entire recipe so we can't be sure but if you have:

```
foo:
        git --version
```

try changing this to:

```
foo:
        git --version;
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Having an entry in my `$PATH` having a directory named `git` within it was indeed the problem, thank you.

Comment: This seems like a bug in `make`.  It should not be trying to execute a directory.  You may want to file a bug report.

Comment: I did say in my answer specifically _There's a bug in GNU make 4.3 (actually the bug was in gnulib, which GNU make uses)_  A bug has already been filed (with gnulib) and resolved, but a new release of GNU make with the fix is not yet published.

Comment: adding a `;` at the end of git command helped. thanks @MadScientist

Comment: I've no `git` string in `$PATH` and am yet affected by this bug. Adding `;` to lines containing `git` in `Makefile` helps, though - thanks!

Comment: I didn't say you had `git` in your `PATH`  I said you have an entry in your `PATH` that contains a directory named `git`.  So if your path contains a directory like `/foo/bar`, then you have a directory named `/foo/bar/git` on your system.